# Error when trying to upload app to itunes

Tags: xcode, submission

So I have xcode 3 and I'm trying to upload an app to the itunes through the application loader. I've already done this multiple times before but I had to renew my itunes connect account and it messed all my certificates up. These are the errors I get.

Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate.

Unable to extract codesigning entitlements from your application. Please make sure "App name" is a valid Mach executable that's properly codesigned.

Now I made sure all the certificates/provisioning profiles/Bundle Ids where correct. I also made sure there where no spaces in the name of the compressed file. And that the codesigning was selected as distribution under the project and target.

What the heck is wrong?

thanks
p.s. Dont tell me I need a new computer and a new xcode...... i know

Comment: Try to delete all your certificates in Keychain and revoke and create new certificates in itunesconnect.

Comment: You need a new computer and a new Xcode :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that the the Apple Certificate you first download to sign all your other certificates has been corrupted. I would start by deleting all the certs from the Keychain, and then downloading the Apple WW Certificate again, then create your certificates and sign them, and finally create your distribution profile.

Comment: @MikeRyanTåndy Then I would say it is probably a bug in XCode 3 or something.